# Xib ViewController

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

This is probably a really simple question and I apologise if it is!!

I have a view controller based application, I move from 1 xib to another using

```
        mainviewcontroller = [[MainViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    [self.view addSubview: mainviewcontroller.view];
```

When I return back to the original view I just use

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

But I want to re-call the viewdidload method. How can I do this without having to create the view again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addSubview` is not the correct way to have a new view controller take over and present it's view set.

Use something like this instead:

```
MainViewController *mainviewcontroller = [[MainViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
[self presentViewController:mainviewcontroller animated:YES completion:completion:^{}];
[mainviewcontroller release];
```

If you are using storyboards, you could always create a segue and call it programmatically or set up through the storyboard itself.

To support pre-iOS 5 devices `UIViewController` also has an older method (which was deprecated in iOS5 and replaced by my original suggestion).

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, I can't use storyboards as this needs to work with older OS. So when I use the above It should call the viewdidload method? am I removing the view ok with the removefromview method?

Comment: This call will replace the existing view controller with the new one you specify. I doubt you'd want to do this on `viewDidLoad` though or your original view/xib/viewcontroller will essentially get bypassed and be non-functional.